# How to increase/decrease from one number to other showing the numbers between them in Ionic 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I get the speed from geolocation and show it on screen. In several cases, the numbers come far from the previous one and I'd like to make a transition showing the numbers in the gap. 
Example:

```
speed 1 -> 80
speed 2 -> 90
display -> 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
```

I tried some solutions but the "transition" didn't work.

location-tracker.ts

```
startTracking(){
  this.watchSubscription = this.watch.subscribe((resp) => {
    this.zone.run(() => {
      var speedToSet = resp.coords.speed;
      this.setSpeed(speedToSet);
    });
  }, error => {
    console.log("Error: " + JSON.stringify(error));
  });
}

setSpeed(speedarg){

  if (speedarg == this.speed){
    return;
  }

  if (speedarg > this.speed){

    let val = this.speed;
    for (var i = val; i <= speedarg; i++){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.speed = i;
      }, 30);
    }
  } else {

    let val = this.speed;
    for (var i = val; i >= speedarg; i--){
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.speed = i;
      }, 30);
    }
  }
}
```

home.html

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
    Speed: {{locationTracker.speed}}
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

I tried the above solution but only the last number is updated.

Example:

```
speed 1 -> 80
speed 2 -> 90
display -> 90
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to do this in Angular would be to utilize Observables.

## Interpolating values

First we cosider a simple function which inteprolates values. We need it to diplay those numbers when going from one speed to another.

```
const interpolate = (from, to) => 
  Array.from({length: Math.abs(to - from) + 1})
    .map((_, i) => to - from > 0 ? from + i : from - i)
```

For example, `interpolate(1, 4)` returns `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. It also handles descending order.

## Stream for changing the speed

We need a stream which will emit speed changes. This will be a `BehaviorSubject`, which means that we ca give it a default value which also automatically be emitted on its creation. We start with a zero.

```
public speed$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0)
```

## Display stream

Our goal is to transform the stream of speed to stream of values which should be displayed on the screen.

```
display$ = this.speed$
  .pairwise()
  .switchMap(([oldSpeed, newSpeed]) => {
    return Observable.of(...interpolate(oldSpeed, newSpeed))
      .map(x => Observable.of(x))
      .map(o => o.delay(30))
      .concatAll()
  })
```

- We use [`pairwise`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-pairwise) to get a previous value as well. If the initial state is `0`, changing speed to `5` will emit `[0, 5]`. Changing speed after that to `2` will emit `[5, 2]`.
- The above values are the ones we need to interpolate over. For `[5, 2]` we create an observable which instantly emits `5`, `4`, `3`, `2` (not an array, but as separate values).
- Then we transform this to a higher-order stream briefly, by [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over each single emitted value to [an observable which emits that same value](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of).
- This allows us to [create a delay](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-delay) for each of those inner streams. We use 30 milliseconds, but it can be changed according to your wishes.
- Now we need to [concat all of these inner streams togehter](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concatAll), which gives us exactly the argment that we want: an observable of values which will be emitted with 30 millisecond delay between them.
- This kind of observable is emitted every time a new pair of values comes along. We use [`switchMap` to flatten it](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap), but also to switch to the next change if the speed is changed before the transition is completed (compare to [`mergeMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-mergeMap) which would allow overlap of flattened streams).
- This gives us the desired stream.

---

That's all! Just 12 lines of code.

Here's [a Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sem21j?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Comment: Perfect! Great solution and great explanation. 
One question: how to initiate with 0 instead of empty or null? So the user can see 0 before the first speed arrives.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's a `startWith` operator. Just append it all the way below after `switchMap`: `}).startWith(0)`.